# Put future inside OnFailure

Tags: scala, future

I am pretty new to scala so be gentle!

I am trying to create a "logical transaction", here is a code sample:

```
val f1:Future[Int] = dao.insertIntoDB
f1.flatmap{
  x => {
    val f2 = sendHttpRequestFuture
    f.onFailure{
       case t => dao.revertDbChangeFuture
    }
 }

 f1.onFailure{
    logger.error("error)
 }
```

So what I think will happened is that the outer onFailure will be executed first, and then the inner onFailure.

The thing is that onFailure return Unit, so it feels weird to put a future inside onFailure, I am not sure what is the right way to handle such use case.

I basically need to revert my changes, and the revert action is asynchronous.

Can you advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play arround with this sample.
It shows how all works.
Actually as I see you've implemented all right.

There are two variables that you can modify `job1Fail` and `job2Fail`.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutFut extends App {


  val f1: Future[Int] = Future {
    doJob
  }

  val job1Fail = false
  val job2Fail = true

  def doJob() = {
    if (job1Fail) sys.error("Failed to do job") else {
      println("job 1 done")
      1
    }
  }

  def doOtherJob() {
    if (job2Fail) sys.error("Failed to do other job") else {
      println("other job done")
    }
  }

  def revertingAll() {
    println("reverting all")
  }

  f1.flatMap {
    x => {
      val f2 = Future {
        doOtherJob()
      }
      f2.onFailure {
        case t => revertingAll()
      }
      f2
    }
  }

  f1.onFailure {
    case t => println("f1 failed")
  }

  Thread.sleep(1000)

}
```

So the results are following:

> db job fail -> output message f1 failed. no revert.
>
> db job ok -> flat map invoked -> http fail -> revert invoked -> f1 does not fail
>
> db job ok -> flat map invoked -> http ok -> all ok -> no revert -> no fail :)

That's are pretty all use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a `revertDbChangeFuture`, because once you have that future, it most often means that you've already triggered the underlying computation, i.e. you are already reverting the DB change, regardless fo the outcome of the insert.
Instead, you should add the **method** for reverting the db change in your `onFailure` callback:

```
insertIntoDBFuture.onFailure {
    case t => revertDbChange()
}

val f1 = insertIntoDBFuture.flatmap(sendHttpRequestFuture(_))
f1.onFailure{
  case t => logger.error("error", t)
}
f1
```

the `flatMap` in `val f1 = insertIntoDBFuture.flatmap(sendHttpRequestFuture(_))` will not be executed if `insertIntoDBFuture` fails, so you don't have to worry about that. Instead, the result of `f1` will be the same failed future, so you will log the error of either `insertIntoDBFuture` or `sendHttpRequestFuture` - or none, if no error occurs.

Comment: I miss lead you, I edited my post again. The code I read indeed look like a code that was already computed. this is not the case due. My question was basically on the behavior of a future inside onFailure clause. When thinking about it a little bit more, it make sense to me that while writing a future inside onFailure, the future will be executed eventually( even after the code already finished). The problem in that is that I can't compose it and control this future. For example if the future inside the onFailure, fails too, I should add onFailure to it also? And Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `recoverWith` API in this case which allows you to transform a failed future with another future:

```
f2.recoverWith({
  case NonFatal(_) => dao.revertDbChangeFuture
})
```

This will return you a Future against the undo operation.